# Junit setup with caliper

Tags: java, junit, caliper

I am trying to wrap the caliper code in junit so the performance tests run as part of my unit tests. It seems to work - the caliper test actually runs, but it doesn't exit successfully. What's the proper way to set this stuff up?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class CaliperBenchmarkExample extends SimpleBenchmark {

        public void timeNanoTime(int reps) {
          for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            System.nanoTime();
          }
        }

    @Test
    public void testPerformance() {
        Runner.main(CaliperBenchmarkExample.class, new String[] { });
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: First suggestion `assertTrue(true)`, It has no sense. Always pass.

Comment: ajozwik: that's why I included it - I'd expect it to pass but it doesn't seem get to it

Comment: In maven test past for me. Maybe the problem is that Runner is called in different thread? Or runner call testPerformance again?

Comment: @user779: `assertTrue(true)` makes no sense at all, it's a no-op, and helps no more than `/* */`. A failed assert throws, a passed assert does nothing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no mechanism to run Caliper tests as JUnit tests. Doing so is complicated because of the way that Caliper forks a child process to isolate your benchmarks. And Caliper benchmarks tend to run for several seconds which may harm test performance.

You may want to investigate [caliper-ci](http://code.google.com/p/caliper-ci/), an open source project that runs Caliper benchmarks continuously.

Comment: Booo. It'd be nice if I could run Caliper benchmarks from the IDE by simply declaring them as tests.